# Manim community edition, Objects not fitting into ThreeDScene with ThreeDAxes

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to generate in manim a ThreeDScene scene with ThreeDAxes. When plotting lines or other objects they don't fit into the coordinate system drawn by the axis. I've already checked several time the manim documentation, but couldn't find any hit to solve the problem. I think the specific thing is, that the axes doesn't have the same length on the negative as on the positive site. It can easily be seen on that sample scene.

```
import numpy as np
from manim import *

class Test(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        axes_defaults = {
            "color": YELLOW,
            "include_numbers": True
        }

        self.set_camera_orientation(phi=65 * DEGREES, theta=45 * DEGREES, distance = 1200)

        ar = [-2,20,1]
        axes = ThreeDAxes(x_range=ar, y_range=ar, z_range=ar, **{"axis_config": axes_defaults})
        axes.add(Dot3D(point=ORIGIN))
        axes.add(Line(start=[-1,0,0], end=[1,0,0]))
        axes.add(Line(start=[0,-1,0], end=[0,1,0]))
        axes.add(Line(start=[0,0,-1], end=[0,0,1]))
        self.add(axes)
        self.wait()
```

This will render to the following picture:
[render output of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZmnx.png)

In the picture you can see that the white lines and the dot, as they are placed on the origin should be placed at the intersections of the three axes.

I'm using the "Manim Community v0.7.0" on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've found the method point_to_coords(point) of the Axis class where ThreeDAxes is derived of. Transforming the Points with this leads to correct visual representation. So before adding the each point needs to be transformed by this method? I don't know I would expect this to work this way. May I didn't get the concept of manim and I'm doing here something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it looks like this when I run it.
[image: a]

A possible solution would be to add the dot and the lines in a diferent VGroup, and then just shift it to the origin of the axes.

Comment: It's not 100% the same as my input. On my, the axes ranges are not the same value on the negative (-2) as on the positive (20) side. On yours it leads to be symmetrical (-5.5. to 5.5) and therefor the origin is the same as the midpoint which is a different situation.

Answer (score 0):

I stumble on this a year later for having the same problem. What fixed mine is specifying not only x_range, y_range, and z_range (I had already done that when I had my problem) but also specify x_length, y_length, z_length. The latter 3 are what fixed my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).